# Geoserver get legend raw data

Tags: geoserver, legend

In geoserver is possible to generate a JSON or XML file with the information necessary to generate a legend in client?

I want to customize further the legend beyond the capabilities of [GetLegendGraphic](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html#controlling-legend-appearance-with-legend-options)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was [proposed](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-81---GetLegendGraphic-as-text-(JSON)) back in 2014 but was not implemented. I would follow up on the users list to see if anyone wants to help provide resources for the GISP.